# Why are these called "meromorphic" differential forms?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, meromorphic-functions

On p.30 of Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves, the notion of a *meromorphic* differential form on a curve $C$ is defined as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $C$ be a curve. The space of (meromorphic) differential forms on $C$, denoted by $\Omega_C$ , is the $\overline{K}(C)$-vector space generated by symbols of the form $dx$ for $x \in \overline{K}(C)$, subject to the usual relations:
>
> (i) $d(x + y) = dx + dy$ for all $x, y \in \overline{K}(C)$.
>
> (ii) $d(xy) = x dy + y dx$ for all $x, y ∈ \overline{K}(C)$.
>
> (iii) $da = 0$ for all $a \in \overline{K}$

However as far as I can tell, meromorphic functions in their full generality don't really appear as coefficients here. For example, we're probably not going to have $e^x dx$ in there. If so, then why is this terminology used? Shouldn't they be called rational differential forms?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but maybe has something to do with Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Note that $x$ is any element of $\overline{K}(C)$, which I assume means something like $K$-valued functions on the curve $C$. In particular, for a unicursal curve, $x$ could be $e^z$ where $z$ is a coordinate on $C$. Then $dx = e^z dz$.

Comment: To be a meromorphic function on a projective curve is quite restrictive, more so than on $\mathbb{C}$. For instance, one can show that the meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ are exactly the rational functions. In particular, $e^z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.